# GCP: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm unable to run django app on gcp app engine.

logs,

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

        at reap_workers (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/arbiter.py:525)
        at handle_chld (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/arbiter.py:242)
        at _releaseLock (/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:223)
```

Comment: have you included gunicorn in your requirements.txt?

Comment: Hi @HaBi could you please check both these similar cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182898/ubuntu-16-04-django-gunicorn-worker-failed-to-boot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975758/gae-production-django-gunicorn-error-haltserver-worker-failed-to-boot-3) and confirm if they help you? It seems that it might be related to some dependencies not being correctly installed or configured to work with GAE.